# Autohotkey: Repeating keypress with key modifier held down

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

How to rebind a key chord with `Ctrl` so that it repeats on multiple presses, while `Ctrl` is held down?

Example: I'm expertimenting with binding `Ctrl`+`Space` to `Backspace`.

```
^Space::Send {BackSpace}
```

When I now press `Ctrl`+`Space` correctly `Backspace` is sent and deletes the last character. I want now to keep `Ctrl` down and delete further characters with multiple `Space` strokes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to use [SendInput](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) and release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>:

```
^Space::sendinput {Ctrl up}{BackSpace}
```

Comment: Thank you but no luck... same behaviour - one BackSpace is sent, on following presses it registers only Space...

Comment: OK - I know what is the problem. You're right that it works with `Ctrl`+`Space`, but I use CapsLock rebound to `Ctrl` and this combination doesn't work... Any tip on that too? {Capslock Up} unfortunately doesn't help...

Comment: Edit the question and describe how you remap Capslock. If it's via AHK then add the relevant code.

Comment: I use a registry-level remapping. It doesn't work that way, but I'll leave the question as it is and accept your original answer, since my problem is very specific...